# JQuery to Prototype for AddThis

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, addthis

I need to put a custom hover menu from http://www.addthis.com/help/toolbox, but Rails uses Prototype whereas the code given is in JQuery. I do not have much experience with either JavaScript library, if someone can help it'd be much appreciated!

```
$(function()
{
    $('.custom_button, .hover_menu').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $('.hover_menu').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.custom_button').addClass('active');
        $(this).data('in', true);
        $('.hover_menu').data('hidden', false);
    }).mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).data('in', false);
        setTimeout(hideMenu, delay);
    });

    var delay = 400;
    function hideMenu()
    {
        if (!$('.custom_button').data('in') && !$('.hover_menu').data('in') && !$('.hover_menu').data('hidden'))
        {
            $('.hover_menu').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.custom_button').removeClass('active');
            $('.hover_menu').data('hidden', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No luck with any answers yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you're not tied down to using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and want to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead, there's a plugin called [jRails](http://ennerchi.com/projects/jrails) which serves as a drop-in replacement for [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/).

Not that there's anything wrong with [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), but getting [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) installed may end up being easier than trying to port it to [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/). Hope that helps (sorry if it isn't exactly what you were looking for).

*EDIT*: [This page](http://jimneath.org/2008/06/18/using-jquery-with-ruby-on-rails/) has some good information about [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/). Hope that helps.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, the problem is the developers don't want to include more libraries than needed (Prototype/Scriptaculous are packaged in, and we're also using YUI)

Comment: Ah, okay. that makes sense, sorry that wasn't much help =/.

Comment: Well if youve already got proto and yui why not go for the full quota and include jQuery and extjs:)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace Prototype with the jRails plugin. Or you can also extend prototype to your needs here is a simple example of a prototype equivalent for data:

```
Element.addMethods({
/**
 * Element#saveData(@element, key, value) -> @element
 * Caches given data
 * $('foo).saveData('keyName', 'Some random data');
 *
 */
saveData: function(element, key, value){
    if (Object.isUndefined(this['ATMCCache']) || !Object.isHash(this['ATMCCache'])){
        this['ATMCCache'] = $H();
    }
    this['ATMCCache'].set(key,value);
    return element;
},
/**
 * Element#getData(@element, key) -> Value or Hash
 * Returns requested key or entire hash
 * $('foo).getData('keyName');
 *
 */
getData: function(element, key){
    return this['ATMCCache'].get(key) || this['ATMCCache'];
},
/**
 * Element#hasData(@element) -> Boolean
 * Returns Boolean if element has any data stored
 * $('foo).hasData();
 *
 */
hasData: function(){
    return !Object.isUndefined(this['ATMCCache']);
}});
```

Just follow the documentation im sure you can take over from here and modify or do as you wish with this code.